# Dictionary as argument for groupby and aggregate dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I use a dictionary as the argument for dataframe groupby and aggregate?

For example, instead of hard coding the arguments like below...

```
grouped_multiple = df.groupby('experience_level','job_title').agg({'salary': ['mean', 'min', 'max']})
```

I would like to use the values of dictionaries as the arguments.

```
a={"1":"experience_level", "2":"job_title"}
b={"1":"salary"}
grouped_multiple = df.groupby(a).agg({b: ['mean', 'min', 'max']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract values from dicts:

```
def groupby_agg(df, groups, funcs):
    g = list(groups.values())
    f = {f: ['mean', 'min', 'max'] for f in funcs.values()}
    return df.groupby(g).agg(f)

a = {'1': 'experience_level', '2': 'job_title'}
b = {'1': 'salary'}
grouped_multiple = groupby_agg(df, a, b)
```